ImportError: cannot import name 'mmr_lmproc' from 'niftypet.nipet.lm'
I am trying to run the PET image reconstruction by using NiftyPET and there is no mmr_lmproc, thus they are throwing an error. 
How do I solve this issue? 
I downloaded the entire NiftyPet Package still the mmr_lmproc is nowhere to be found.
Below is the error message that I am getting. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
# create histogram

mMRpars\['Cnt'\]\['BTP'\] = 0
m = nipet.mmrhist(datain, mMRpars, outpath=opth, store=True, use_stored=True)
if totCnt:
    mMRpars\['Cnt'\]\['BTP'\] = 2  # enable parametric bootstrap
    mMRpars\['Cnt'\]\['BTPRT'\] = totCnt / m\['psino'\].sum()  # ratio count level relative to the      original
    m = nipet.mmrhist(datain, mMRpars, outpath=path.join(opth, 'BTP', '%.3g' % totCnt), store=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In\[3\], line 3
  m = nipet.mmrhist(datain, mMRpars, outpath=opth, store=True, use_stored=True)

File \~\\NIPET\\niftypet\\nipet\\lm\\mmrhist.py:36 in mmrhist
  return hist(datain, txLUT, axLUT, Cnt, frms=frms, use_stored=use_stored, store=store,

File \~\\NIPET\\niftypet\\nipet\\lm\\mmrhist.py:58 in hist
  from . import mmr_lmproc

ImportError: cannot import name 'mmr_lmproc' from 'niftypet.nipet.lm' (C:\\Users\\Dell\\NIPET\\niftypet\\nipet\\lm\__init_\_.py)

Expecting to locate or download  'mmr_lmproc' from somewhere, but how can I do this???

THis is what i get when I check for the file (No mmr_lmproc to be found) : import niftypet.nipet.lm as lm
print(dir(lm))
['all', 'builtins', 'cached', 'doc', 'file', 'loader', 'name', 'package', 'path', 'spec', 'auxilary_frames', 'draw_frames', 'dynamic_timings', 'frame_position', 'get_time_offset', 'mmrhist', 'randoms', 'split_frames']
